# A member of the > type, 'ClassID', does not have a corresponding column in the data > reader with the same name

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, subquery

I've created this Stored Procedure which may be a bit long but it works nevertheless. However, i'm  using entity framework to complete this project. However when it runs it gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the
>   specified 'SchoolsModel.TeacherClassesSorting_Result'. A member of the
>   type, 'ClassID', does not have a corresponding column in the data
>   reader with the same name.

here is my SP that i created in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TeacherClassesSorting] 
@ID int,
@sub int,
@frm int,
@trm int,
@yr nvarchar(15)
AS 
BEGIN
--SORTING BY ID ONLY
IF @trm IS NULL and @frm IS NULL and @sub IS NULL AND @yr IS NULL
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID 
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, c.FormID DESC
END

--Sorting by Year
ELSE IF @yr IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
--SORTING BY ID AND YEAR
IF @trm >0 and @frm IS NULL and @sub IS NULL
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID and c.AcademicYear = @yr and c.TermID = @trm
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, Form DESC
END

ELSE
IF @trm >0 and @frm >0 and @sub IS NULL
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID and c.AcademicYear = @yr and c.TermID = @trm AND C.FormID = @frm
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, Form DESC
END

ELSE
IF @trm >0 and @frm IS NULL and @sub >0
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID and c.AcademicYear = @yr and c.TermID = @trm AND C.SubjectCode = @sub
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, Form DESC
END


ELSE
IF @trm IS NULL and @frm IS NULL and @sub >0
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID and c.AcademicYear = @yr AND C.SubjectCode = @sub
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, Form DESC
END

ELSE
IF @trm IS NULL and @frm >0 and @sub >0
BEGIN
select c.ClassID as ID,sub.SubjectName as Subject, f.FormName as Form, trm.TermName as AcademicTerm , c.AcademicYear as AcademicYear
from Teachers as t inner join Classes as c on t.TeacherID = c.TeacherID 
              inner join Subjects as sub on sub.SubjectCode = c.SubjectCode
              inner join Terms as trm on trm.TermID = c.TermID
              inner join SchoolForms as f on f.FormID = c.FormID 
where         t.UserID = @ID and c.AcademicYear = @yr AND C.SubjectCode = @sub AND C.FormID = @frm
ORDER BY AcademicYear DESC, Form DESC
END
```

I'm new to programming so please bear with me i'm not perfect at this. Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: Add lines of code from where you are getting error.

Comment: Perhaps add a select statement in the stored procedure that would run if all parameters are NULL (ie the default) - IF trm IS NULL and frm IS NULL and sub IS NULL AND yr IS NULL and ID IS NULL

Comment: in the code snippet above there is a select statement for what you stated @Brendan